# Intel 82865G Graphics Controller - making it work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

RE:

Putting this out there in case someone else runs into this issue. The intel chipset is on-board. I discovered the reason for the crappy resolution in windows 7 was that the memory to share with the video card was set to 1MB in the BIOS. I changed this to 8MB (the maximum) and then the PC rebooted I was able to select a higher resolution.
link|flag answered Aug 18 '09 at 5:53
Nick Kavadias

Nick,

Does this give Aero functionalty ?

Comment: No, tried it on my old Dell laptop, and I looked high and low for a workaround, none available, no Aero on the 865 graphics. :-(

Answer (score 1):

No

Unfortunately it is too old for standard drivers, let alone full Aero functionality.

[See here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=1044&DwnldID=18576&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss)

Comment: Yeah, you can get a decent look, but since this is software simulated-hardware accel, expect a performance hit if you do enable transparencies, etc.